# Ways to output "negative" components of a sine wave through an op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

I have two sine waves of 1V magnitude and offset of 2.5V with 180 phase difference, going into a differential amplifier to be amplified. I have access to a 5V source (as a source, not as a battery) and ground.

Since the output will sometimes be negative, the lack of a negative source means the op-amp cannot drive the output to a negative component. I have a few ideas to overcome this:

1. Generate a -5V voltage to be used in powering the op-amp.
2. Generate a 2.5V voltage to act as a ground for the differential amplifier inputs, and therefore act as an offset. I don't have access to regulator ICs so I'll need to make this out of an op-amp. This is my preferred method but I would like to know less current-intensive methods.

I would like to know if there are more options that I have overlooked.

Comment: You don't say if the opamp circuit has any gain, or is it just a unity-gain common-mode rejecter.  Also, what opamps are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods 1 and 2 are common solutions.  Which one usually depends on other circuit factors such as tolerance for the noise of a charge pump to generate the -5V, or the availability of an extra opamp to create the +2.5 V offset reference.

A possible issue with the 2.5 V reference approach is that any difference between it and the 2.5 V DC offset already built into the input signals will appear at the opamp output, possible pushing one of the peaks into clipping.  One way around this is to lowpass filter one of the input signals to extract its DC value, and buffer that to use as the non-inverting input offset.  Messy and lotsa parts, but self-tracking.

Absent more information, I'm leaning toward the -5 V charge pump approach.  A CMOS 555 is relatively quiet, or use an opamp as a Schmitt trigger oscillator (or a Schmitt trigger gate if there is a spare one in the design).